# Is it dangerous to display the id of an Firestore document to the user?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i was wondering if its dangerous to show the user the id, which Firebase Cloud Firestore generates when creating an new document

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no, it is not dangerous, unless you are using that document ID as a secret key somewhere else in your system.  Since we don't know exactly how you're using this ID, it's not really possible to say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Primary Keys are usually shown to users. May it be your bank account number, your user id on platform X - it's not a problem in general, as long as the access in your application is limited properly.